JDK 21 ForkJoinPool Stucked In Unknown State
Recently one of the instances of our service run into an abnormal state.
This instance is run with JDK 21 (OpenJDK build 21+35-2513) and virtual thread enabled.
This anormal instance is still able to answer request but it's CPU consumption is 100%.
From jstack printing, it looks like that ForkJoinPool-workers are the major CPU consuming threads.
#144699 "ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1944"
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1808)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:188)

From jcmd printing, no virtual threads is actually running.
It looks like a JDK bug but I lack some idea to confirm it.

There is no indicator that this thread is responsible for the 100% CPU consumption. However, the number 1944 in the thread name is quite alarming…
